# Does it make sense to buy a compatible Mac external disk?

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, external-disk, disk-format

What is the advantage of buying a compatible Mac external disk?
Using [Tuxera NTFS](http://www.tuxera.com/products/tuxera-ntfs-for-mac/) I can have an external disk for both, the windows partition (or any windows machine) as well as for the Mac one.

Does it make sense to look for a compatible external disk nowadays? 
What would be the best way to deal with the PC/Mac compatible problems in terms of disk formatting? Is using Tuxera a nice way to deal with it?

Comment: Maybe you want to ask about how to format a disk?  The actual disk doesn't matter, as all external disks can be reformatted to whichever format you prefer.

Comment: @Steve This article maybe of assistance http://www.mactip.net/guide-how-to-format-an-external-drive-to-work-seamlessly-with-macs-and-pcs-without-third-party-software/

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can format any hard disk to macos journaled if you like. So buy the hdd you want, partition it and format it as you like.

If you format it as FAT you can use it on both win and mac for read/write, but you cannot use it for time machine backups (time machine requires macos filesystem).

Answer (score 2):

You can get any external disk and use it. If you wish to use NTFS as the data interchange format between OS X and Windows, then products like [Tuxera NTFS for Mac](http://www.tuxera.com/products/tuxera-ntfs-for-mac/) or [Paragon NTFS for Mac](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/) or even free ones like [NTFS-3G for Mac OS X](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/NTFS-3G) would do.

On the other hand, if you wish to use HFS+ as the interchange format, you can use [Paragon HFS for Windows](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/hfs-windows/).

Both the above approaches would allow you to deal with files larger than 4GB, which is a limitation of the third option, using FAT32 format for the external disk.